# My delete operation not working properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react+redux. This is my delete code(I wanted to use filter on object):

```
(state, action) => {
                      return Object.keys(state)
                          .filter( index => {
                            return state[index].id !== action.id
                          }).reduce( (acc, index) => {
                            return (acc[index] = state[index], acc)
                          }, {});
                        }
```

so my state is like this

```
[{id:123,text:"hi there"}, {idL456, text:"hello world"}]
```

I have this error when I invoke my delete operation, can't figure out why?

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `todos[0]` is marked as required
>   in `TodoList`, but its value is `undefined`.
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined and my array of object becomes like this(assume I have 1 item I want to delete):

```
[undefined]
```

I don't know why it has length?:

```
[
0: undefined
length: 1
]
```

help?

Comment: Because the array contains the value `undefined`, as you can see by `0: undefined`.  So you seem to be assigning `undefined` to `todos[0]`. `[undefined]` is not the same as `[]`.

Comment: @FelixKling Is there something wrong with my delete operation? I'd like to ask for help, tried it on my console but it seems to work

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: There are bunch of weird things going on here. E.g. you are saying that your state is an array, yet this function seems to return an object. Why are changing the state from an array to an object? And if the state is really an array, why use `Object.keys` at all and not just do `return state.filter(o => o.id === action.id);`? A complete example would certainly be more helpful. I could imagine the problem is somehow related to the fact that this function can return an object such as `{1: {...}}` and somewhere else you are converting this back to an array....

Comment: ...., incorrectly iterating over the properties (e.g. `for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj).length; i++)`) and accessing `obj[0]` which doesn't exist.

Comment: @FelixKling All clear. I'll accept your comment as answer. Thanks